# Get axis name in tooltip on Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using a bubble chart in Highcharts and I am trying to change the hover tooltip to show more meaningful output - at the moment I can get it to show the axis values but I cannot get it to show the labels.

I am using this in my plotoptions:

```
plotOptions: {
    bubble: {
        minSize: 1,
        maxSize: 40,
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x}:00 UTC on {point.y} => total of {point.z} tickets'
        }                   
    }       
}
```

and in my y axis I have:

```
yAxis:{
    categories: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday","Sunday"]
}
```

which displays as:

```
11:00 on 0 => total of 32 tickets
```

but I would like it to show the actual day in the label:

```
11:00 on Monday => total of 32 tickets
```

I have looked at formatter but then I cannot seem to access the z axis as it gives an undefined.

How can I use the y axis name in the tooltip?

http://jsfiddle.net/qvw5gurc/1/

Comment: You may have to switch to `tooltip.formatter`, but not absolutely certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Ondkloss said in their comment, use [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) instead:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br>' + this.point.x + ':00 UTC on ' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '=> total on ' + this.point.z + 'tickets';
        }
    },
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvw5gurc/2/).

Comment: @Kondal, as I answered in the answer above, use a `formatter` function, you have access to more data about the point.  See updated [code here](https://jsfiddle.net/7kLkh7ya/25/).